# Generating uniformly distributed random numbers in distributed environment

Tags: database, random, p2p, uuid, boost-uuid

I have to generate a "unique Random Number" in a Wireless sensor network which works on the principle of Gossiping.

The requirements are:

1. Each node has to generate a **unique Random Number**, *without
   having any shared knowledge of what other nodes have generated.*
2. The *Distribution of the generated Random number should be uniform with
   respect to each other*.
3. It would be preferable if the range of the generated random number is around 10-16 bits or may be lesser.

The limitations are:

1. One node has no idea what number the other nodes in the network are generating.
2. Implementation in C, C++.

I also have the provision of using a unique seed for random number generation. the seed could be any number in the range **0-2^15**.

If there is no way of generating such numbers, then it would be helpful if there is any method by which I can meet some of the above requirements.

If you can suggest me some way to achieve this result it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this solution to work you must know the total number of nodes in the generation network. let this number be `n`.

the basic idea is to generate uniformly distributed random numbers on each participating node inside a given interval. the `n` intervals of the participating nodes must not overlap.
a shared seed does not complicate matters if the total number of nodes does not change and each node can be assigned statically some integer `i` <= `n` such that each number is issued exactly once. instead of generating a single random number on each turn, `n` numbers are generated, and node `i` takes the `i`-th number from this series.

however, the overall distribution of random numbers generated will not be uniform unless ...:

- you synchronize random number generation.
- all intervals have the same size.

for information on random number generation on individual nodes [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).